# Множественное объединение таблиц в PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

У меня 4 таблицы:

```
 //car
 id_car | name  | id_wheel | id_motor | id_transmission 
--------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------
      1 | car_1 |        1 |        1 |               1
      2 | car_2 |        2 |        2 |               2

 //motor
 id_motor |   name   
----------+----------
        1 | motor_01
        2 | motor_02
        3 | motor_03

 //wheel
 id_wheel |   name   
----------+----------
        1 | wheel_01
        2 | wheel_02
        3 | wheel_03

 //transmission
 id_transmission |   name   
-----------------+----------
               1 | trans_01
               2 | trans_02
               3 | trans_03
```

У таблицы `car` поля `id_wheel`, `id_moto`, `id_transmission` ссылаются на соответсвующие поля в других таблицах. Кроме этих трех больше здесь нигде ссылок нет.

У меня задача написать скрипт запроса возвращающий все имена неиспользуемых деталей.

С начала я написал так:

```
select m.name from motor as m
left outer join car as c on m.id_motor = c.id_motor where c.name is null;
```

Но когда я захотел прибавить в тот же запрос неиспользуемые детали из остальных таблиц, понял что в тупике так как основная таблица у меня может быть только одна...

Помогите пожалуйста написать такой запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 'motor' part_type, m.name part_name
    FROM motor m
    LEFT JOIN car c ON m.id_motor = c.id_motor 
    WHERE c.id_motor IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wheel', w.name 
    FROM wheel w
    LEFT JOIN car c ON w.id_wheel = c.id_wheel 
    WHERE c.id_wheel IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'transmission', t.name 
    FROM transmission t
    LEFT JOIN car c ON t.id_transmission = c.id_transmission
    WHERE c.id_transmission IS NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Желать же получить список в 3 поля несколько странно - при этом должно получиться, что в одной записи будут собраны запчасти, на самом деле никак меж собой не связанные, что неверно чисто идеологически. Впрочем, если ОЧЕНЬ хочется - 3 отдельных подзапроса, заодно пронумеровать в них отобранные записи, и соединить по этим номерам.

Comment: а `SELECT 'motor' type, m.name name` это как ? тут надо что-то подставить?

Comment: О_О Ничего тут не надо подставлять... в выходной набор будет помещено 2 поля, в первом строковый литерал 'motor' с присвоением ему имени type, во втором - значение из поля m.name с присвоением ему имени name.

Comment: вот как есть: `
LINE 1: SELECT 'motor' type, m.name name`
                       ^ это копи паст стрелочка на type указывает

Comment: Значит, это зарезервированное слово. Замените, например, на part_type. И на всякий случай, замените name на part_name... текст запроса подкорректировал.